# Why do I have to put part of my condition in parenthesis to prevent a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, selector

Here is my code:

```
if(typeof selector = "string") {
```

When I ran the code, I for a syntax error saying: `SyntaxError: Expected token ')'` To try to prevent that, I put the `typeof selector` part into parenthesis. So here is my new code:

```
if((typeof selector) = "string") {
```

No syntax error.

Why do I have to put part of my condition in parenthesis to prevent this syntax error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using a single equals sign

```
if (typeof selector = "string") {
```

Which is an assignment, rather than

```
if (typeof selector === "string") {
```

Which is the equality operator.  Its generally better to use === rather then == as this is the more 'type safe' comparison.

(As a side note I was curious why the second example didn't throw an exception so tried it in the node.js console.  Both `typeof selector = "string"` and `(typeof selector) = "string"` throw exceptions in that environment - I guess its browser dependent)

Answer (score 2):

```
typeof selector == "string"
```

use `==`

or practice using `===` which is best to avoid confusion over falsy values in JS